# Why Does ScheduledExecutorService Cause Memory Leak with 'New' Keyword

Tags: java, memory, memory-leaks, heap-memory

When I try using a `ScheduledExecutorService` to execute the following code:

```
ScheduledExecutorService scheduledExecutor = Executors.newScheduledThreadPool(1);
scheduledExecutor.scheduleAtFixedRate(new TaskA(), 0, 1800, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
```

This produces a memory leak (memory usage keeps growing so that within 12 hrs I'm using 90%+  memory on my machine (which eventually causes Eclipse to crash due to lack of memory) , even though program only uses about 50% memory after 1-2 runs)

However, when I change it to:

```
ScheduledExecutorService scheduledExecutor = Executors.newScheduledThreadPool(1);

final TaskA taskA = new TaskA();
scheduledExecutor.scheduleAtFixedRate(taskA, 0, 1800, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
```

Seems to release memory just fine.

Why does the first code cause memory to leak and second not? Isn't all memory garbage collected as soon as the thread finishes executing?

Comment: In 1st snippet, you are creating a thread pool of 2 threads. "ScheduledExecutorService scheduledExecutor = Executors.newScheduledThreadPool(2); ".          But in the 2nd snippet you are creating thread pool of size 1- ScheduledExecutorService scheduledExecutor = Executors.newScheduledThreadPool(1);.             Are you sure with the same no of threads there is no memory leak? Also did you do any profiling of memory at certain interval to see where the memory leak is happening?

Comment: @RahulVedpathak I corrected the code. The number of threads do not make a difference. I did some profiling with YourKit but was not able to uncover the cause.

Comment: 2 things: 1. the fact that the JVM uses the memory you allocated to it doesn't mean there is a leak. It's free to execute the GC whenever it wants to. The thread never finishes: you ask it to execute the same task every 1800 seconds.

Comment: @JBNizet 1.But why does the amount of memory keep growing from one execution to the next?  If it's conserving memory from before it should not grow with every iteration.. 2. If that's the case, how do you understand the difference between the two code snippets in the OP? Why does the second code snippet clean memory correctly..

Comment: 1. Without code, how could we know? 2. The two snippets are basically identical. If there is a difference, it's probably caused by some other difference.

Comment: What does your task do? Does it create/load some objects into the memory?
Also to collect the objects , the objects should not have any references. So are you making sure that the Task is not keeping the references of the Objects alive?

Comment: @RahulVedpathak  My task basically scrapes tons of web pages and then loads the data into local objects for analysis. In any case, I don't see how anything could live beyond when the thread lives. After the thread calling scheduleAtFixedRate() finishes shouldn't all memory associated with the task be released? I don't see how it could still hold onto the memory if the thread finished (which I see it did).. (I have no references to Future)